# Pointers vs Allocatable variables in fortran

Tags: fortran

What is the difference between a pointer vector/matrix with an allocatable vector/matrix? What is the benefit to use pointers in fortran? Or when it is better to use pointers instead of an allocatable variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ALLOCATABLE arrays or POINTER arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300199/allocatable-arrays-or-pointer-arrays)

Comment: Executive summary of the linked answer: Use allocatables